# Swing_Frame_Unable to get output for the animation code

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, frame

```
Code :
```

```
        public class SimpleAnimation {          
            int x=70;
            int y=70;           
            public static void main(String[] args) {                
                SimpleAnimation gui = new SimpleAnimation();
                gui.go();               
            }           
            public void go()            
            {               
                System.out.println("go");
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
                MyDrawPanel mdp = new MyDrawPanel();
                frame.getContentPane().add(mdp);        
                frame.setSize(300,300);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("go");           
                for(int i=0;i<130;i++) {                    
                    x++;
                    y++;
                        mdp.repaint();                  
                    System.out.println("go");                   
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }                               
            }           
            class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel{               
                public void painComponent(Graphics g) {                 
                    g.setColor(Color.white);
                    g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
                        g.setColor(Color.green);
                    g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
                }  
            }
        
        }
```

Query :
The output should be frame filled with white background and round small circle rounds in the a circle. But output is only an empty frame. what would be the missed one? I have used the JPanel extended class as inner class. Could someone help on getting the desired output?

```
***************************************************************************************
```

Comment: You're going to want to start by reading [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) which not only provides the information about why you approach doesn't work, but how you might go about fixing it

Answer (score 2):

Swing is single threaded and not thread safe.

This means that you should not block the event dispatching thread with things like `Thread.sleep` and you should not update the UI or properties the UI relies on from outside of the event dispatching thread.

You should read through [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) which will provide you with more information.

The next issue is you've misspelt `painComponent`, it should be `paintComponent`.  This is where using `@Override` to mark methods you thinking you're overriding is important, as it will generate a compiler error if not method exists in the parent classes

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SimpleAnimation {

    int x = 70;
    int y = 70;
    int tick = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleAnimation gui = new SimpleAnimation();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        System.out.println("go");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyDrawPanel mdp = new MyDrawPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(mdp);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("go");

        Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tick++;
                if (tick > 129) {
                    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                }
                x++;
                y++;
                mdp.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

        public MyDrawPanel() {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 40, 40);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your MyDrawPanel does not override the `paintComponent` method (you missed a 't'), this should be:

```
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
```

Note that the (optional) `@Override` annotation yields a compile error in case you have a typo, so it's good practice to add it.

Comment: thank you, now the overridden paintComponent() method worked fine